# Can't log in to website with Python requests session module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, web-scraping

I am just starting out with web scraping. For my first project, I'm trying to log into artofproblemsolving.com using requests.Session() and access another user's account. Here is my code:

```
import requests

LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/ucp.php?mode=login'
DATA_URL = 'https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=90586'

payload = {
    'username': '{{my_username}}',
    'password': '{{my_password}}'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    r = s.get(DATA_URL)
    print r.text
```

But when I run this in terminal, the output HTML is from the login page, not the user's profile that I'm trying to grab. I double-checked that LOGIN_URL is the POST action in the login form, that 'username' and 'password' are the names of the form items, and that my login information is correct.

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hey quick question! where did you install your requests module? I am trouble finding one :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is direct reason for the problem. But there are another parameter that the form send to login action.

Beside `username`, `password`, also pass following parameters:

```
'username': username,
'password': password,
'login': 'Login'.
'sid': sid,   # You need to parse the login page to get sid
'redirect': 'index.php',
```

Comment: Brilliant! You were totally right. Thank you so much!

Comment: This helped steer me in the right direction. Hidden inputs not sent as post data made my login fail.