# Python requests post login not working for this site

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I've tried everything to try to login to this site with sessions and python requests but it doesn't seem to work and keeps redirecting me to the login page when I try to access the protected url. (status_code = 302)

```
import time
import smtplib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html

url = "https://beatyourcourse.com/school_required#"
protected_url = "https://beatyourcourse.com/flyering"

session = requests.Session()
responce = session.get(url)

tree = html.fromstring(responce.text)
token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='authenticity_token']/@value")))[0]

payload = {
    'user[email]' : '****',
    'user[password]' : '****',
    'authenticity_token' : token
}

responce = session.post(url, data = payload)    #Logging in

responce = session.get(protected_url)   # visiting protected url

print responce.url  # prints "https://beatyourcourse.com/school_required#" (redirected to login page)
```

Comment: Are you sure the field names names `user[email]` and `user[password]` are correct?  It seems quite unusual to have brackets embedded inside field names.

Comment: @JohnGordon this is the actual element on the site: <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required" type="email" name="user[email]" id="user_email">

Comment: So like this?
    responce = session.get(url)

    responce = session.post(url, data = payload) #Logging in

    responce = session.get(protected_url) # visiting protected url

Comment: Never mind that last comment, I didn't see that you had already done a `GET` on the url.

Comment: @JohnGordon Maybe it's something specific about the login functionality of this site?

Comment: Why are you calling `list(set(...))[0]` on the authenticity token value?  Is there more than one authenticity token on the page?

Comment: No, you're right I probably didn't need to refer to it as a list. But that part is working so I don't think it's that.

Comment: Have you looked at the page source to see if it has any javascript?  Maybe there is some sneaky javascript manipulation going on, which `requests` will not do.

Comment: Can you log in successfully from a normal browser?

Comment: @JohnGordon No, I'm kinda new to this and not super sure how to do that. However after reading this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225700/cant-log-in-to-website-with-python-requests-session-module) I learned that there can me some hidden input parameters on the site. For example they found a "login" and "Sid" input for that site, do you know how they or someone would find the other hidden input values?

Comment: "hidden" input values must still be present in the page html source.

Comment: Does the page source have any `<script>` tags?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yea, like 20 of them. I have to search each one to find where the button functionality is?

Comment: @JohnGordon I've tried looking through the code and trying a bunch of stuff. I think might just try using a webbot to manually log in before using requests